# Having problem joining (make segment) two curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to join two curves without success.
I can extrude a single curve (E).
I can close a single curve (F).
Using 2.8 on Linux.
The 2.8 docs may be from an earlier 2.8 beta?
Thanks,
Ajlogo
[image: make segment problem]

Comment: You can't join curves from separate objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press ctrl-J to join them before going into edit mode. Then it should work.

Comment: Works. The docs should be updated.